Dynamically pass ID of a control to a C# function on onchange event
I am converting an existing ASP.NET application into Blazor app.
I have this form
<table width='400px' style="border-width:2" ><!-- Start Hub table 
                <tr>
                    <td>Role</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Phone</td>
                    <td>email / mobile</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:140px;">Event Hub Manager</td>
                    <td><input id="block1_role1_names" @onchange=@(async(e) => await update_details("block1_role1_names", e)) value="@getContact("block1_role1_names")" class="NameColumn" /></td>
                    <td  style="width:80px;">3664 8462</td>
                    <td><input id="block1_role1_phone" @onchange=@(async(e) => await update_details("block1_role1_phone", e)) value="@getContact("block1_role1_phone")" class="PhoneColumn" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>

When page loads, I call a function "getContact" and pass the id of the control and it loads value from a json file.
When I make any update in a text box, I call "update_details" and pass the id of the control and write into a json file.
protected async Task update_details(string controlId, ChangeEventArgs controlEvent)
{
    //save into json based on id and vaule
}


private string getContact(string Id)
{
    
    return "get from josn file based on id";
}

It is all working fine.
I have more than 50 rows and for every row, I have 2 text boxes and to get values of those 2 boxes, I have to pass IDs.
I don't want to manually pass IDs into functions, I want something dynamic, every textbox has its own Id, so onchange and value function should take that ID as a parameter, something like this
<input id="block1_role1_names" @onchange=@(async(e) => await update_details(ID_OF_THE_CONTROL, e)) value="@getContact(ID_OF_THE_CONTROL)" class="NameColumn" />

How can I pass the ID of the textbox into those 2 functions?
When I tried passing "this", this refers to the page and not the textbox.

In my humble opinion, Blazor is not Dom-oriented but data-oriented, so that we are not able to get the target DOM/element of the target DOM in onchange event. Maybe pass the id manually as the parameter is the best option.

dont use code snippets for pasting blazor code. use code sample blocks (ctrl+q).


I have more than 50 rows and for every row, I have 2 text boxes and to get values of those 2 boxes...so onchange and value function should take that ID as a parameter, something like this

Blazor does not support this kind of interaction with DOM. It's not how forms are done in blazor.
You should bind inputs to your data classes and then access those data classes instead of DOM.
For example:
@foreach(var contact in contacts)
{
  <tr>
       <td><input @bind="contact.Name" @bind:after="() => Save(contact)" class="NameColumn" /></td>
       <td><input @bind="contact.Phone" @bind:after="() => Save(contact)"  class="PhoneColumn" /></td>                
  </tr>
}

@code 
{   
    class Contacts
    {
        public string Name {get; set;};
        public string Phone {get; set;};
    }
    
    List<Contact> contacts = new();
    
    override void OnInitialized()
    {
        string json = ...;
        contacts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Contact>>();
    }
    
    async Task Save(Contact contact)
    {
        //todo: save contact
    }
}


Notice that @bind automatically updates contact instance when user types into textbox.

Since you're hard-coding the ID, then you can just hard-code the ID in the handler lambda to do what you want.:
<input id="block1_role1_names" @onchange=@(async(e) => await update_details("block1_role1_names", e)) value="@getContact("block1_role1_names")" class="NameColumn" />

However, don't.  You don't NEED any id at all, and you should not be trying to get that id programatically.  You should get any IDs from your data, i.e. have an ID column in the class representing a line of data.

Thank you for replying, now I have to add "block1_role1_names" 3 times for every control, If I have 100 controls, I will be adding IDs 300 times which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I just want to specify ID only 1 time for a control and then C# function should take that ID in the parameters, just like update_details(this.id, e) instead of update_details("block1_role1_names", e)

I can simplify this: you think that the code is a tool for handling the DOM objects.  This is not correct.  In Blazor, the DOM is an expression of the C# data.  Show us what C# data you have, and we'll show you how to correctly express and interact with it in your markup.
